# No valid sudoers sources

Tags: rhel, sudo

I've gone through the Google searches, but the results always have an extra clue that I'm not seeing. The error:

```
[testuser@testhost] $ sudo -ll
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

That's it. No parse errors in /etc/sudoers, nothing.

- /etc/sudoers is owned by root:root and has 0440 permissions.
- I ran `visudo` to uncomment the included `%wheel` group privilege.
- My test user is a member of `wheel`.
- I've even removed and reinstalled `sudo-1.8.6p3-7.el6.x86_64` on this RHEL 6.4 test VM.

What else can I look at?

Answers to questions:

- The VM I'm testing on is secure; I can't copy/paste to an outside site. (I'm asking this question from a different host outside the firewall.) `stat /etc/sudoers` shows a regular file of `size 4000` and `access 0440`. The contents of the file are default (via the remove and reinstall) with the exception of the `%wheel` group being uncommented.
- `ls -ld /etc/sudo*` shows

  - `/etc/sudo.conf` (0640, root:root)
  - `/etc/sudoers` (0440, root:root)
  - `/etc/sudoers.d` (0750, root:root, empty directory)
  - `/etc/sudo-ldap.conf` (0640, root:root)

The overall goal is [privileges via ldap](http://www.sudo.ws/sudoers.ldap.man.html), which I've done before successfully.

Thanks!

[CORRECTION: The uncommented `%wheel` group is not password-free. The test user must enter a password for wheel privileges.]

[UPDATE 1011h: Modifying `/etc/sudo-ldap.conf` with the correct `sudoers_base` got me access to the LDAP database (anonymous bind during testing) and a successful result to `sudo -ll`. That's a workaround for me, but doesn't solve the initial problem of whatever is preventing sudoers from working locally.]

Comment: What is the output of `stat /etc/sudoers`, and `cat /etc/sudoers`?

Comment: Is sudoers.d directory also owned by root:root? Just covering all bases first.

Comment: What do you have for `sudoers:` in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying `/etc/sudo-ldap.conf` with correct information got me a good result to `sudo -ll` for my test user. I count that is a workaround, though. It doesn't solve the problem of why sudo won't work with solely local information.

Comment: As an idea, you might check nsswitch.conf to see if "files" is one of the configured sources for sudo.

Comment: The sudoers setting in nsswitch.conf is "files ldap." Once I'm done proving LDAP's utility to my bosses, I'll switch those on all clients.... ;-)